# How to know max size for hsqldb in-memory database

Tags: hsqldb, in-memory

I want to know how much memory occupies for a HSQLDB in-memory database and further I would like to increase the size of a memory(RAM) so that I can load more data into hsqldb database for processing.

Answer (score 0):

The memory used is part of the Java heap. You can use Java API calls to check how much heap space is used and how much is left. A small HSQLDB database can work in about 32MB of heap space.

You use the Java -Xmx setting to increase the allocated heap when you start your program that embeds HSQLDB, or a standalone HSQLDB server.